# Don't use tmpfs for /tmp in WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, ubuntu-20.04

I am running *Ubuntu 20.04* in *WSL2*.
I have the problem that there is not enough space in `/tmp`.
It is located in *tmpfs*. I'd like to move it into `/` so that it can use the space of this much bigger partition.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/linux/move-tmp-to-another-partition

Comment: It shows how to create a new partition, but I'd rather just have it on the root partition, so I don't have to decide on a fixed size.

Comment: You can skip partition creation and formatting. It also shows how to move `/tmp` of a running system safely to a new location (which can be any location) and how to mount the new `/tmp` in `fstab`.